# Gmap Views Module - Popups are too big

Tags: 7, views, google-maps

I'm using GMAP module and its views counterpart.  The issue I'm having is that I'm using a custom text field to display fields wrapped in HTML that I have pulled in from the query.  However, the popup won't size correctly; it ends up being too big. This is my code for Custom Text Field:

```
<div id="col1">
  [field_thtr_img_fid]
</div>
<div id="col2">
  <h5>[title]</h5>
  [address_1]
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looking at the details from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186047/drupal-gmap-views-popups-are-too-big I would suggest to wrap everything in the custom text field in a div with a specific class then do .myclass { width: DESIRED_WIDTH; } in your stylesheet.

or try to `div.gmnoprint .views-field-nothing { width: DESIRED_WIDTH; }` where `div.gmnoprint` is the wrapper div for the gmap popup and `.views-field-nothing` is the default wrapper for a custom text field in views.

Without a live example, it is harder to give an exact answer. I suspect you may have to add `overflow:hidden;` to your wrapper div if you have any floating going on there.